# Help with philosophical redefining of elements

Tags: philosophy

So I am trying to re-explain the elements in the Brihat Samhita by looking at what each element brings to the table versus what it does on its own using atma. Here is the link to this verse: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brihat-samhita/d/doc229329.html or The main property of earth is smell, a quality discernible by the nose; that of water is taste, a quality discernible by the tongue; that of fire or light is shape or appearance, discernible by the eye; that of the air is touch, discernible by the body; and that of Ākāśa is sound, discernible by the ear. Now suppose the Daśā period to be that of Venus. His element is water; the quality belonging to water is taste, discernible by the tongue; therefore in the Daśā period of Venus, the person will eat juicy meals according to his desire. Again, suppose the Daśā period to be that of Jupiter, his elementary principle is Ākāśa; its property is sound, discernible by the ear; the person’s speech will be sweet and agreeable to the ear. In the Daśā period of Mercury (earth, smell) the person’s body will be with an agreeable odour: in the period of Mars (fire, sight), he will be of agreeable appearance, and in that of Saturn (air, touch), he will be of soft body. From these the particular Daśā period of a person may be ascertained.

So for Akasa, I stated how Akasa brings space allowing sound to move through to other molecules and without it, everything is stuck together and nothing can vibrate. However, if we strip Akasa and have it alone we simply have a vacuum ie space where it doesn't exist. Similarly, light/fire allows us to see various colors ie photons split and different objects reflect different light colors. Without it who knows what we can see? If we only have a world made of light ie we exist in a single photon it would just be energy and we cannot discern anything. In short, I see what each element brings to the table. However, I am having trouble understanding why the other elements are linked with their specific sense and if this methodology works. A little help would be lovely.

Comment: *What atma does?* Nothing. It's just a witness: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGKFTUuJppU

Comment: Hence it is the observer